# Ошибка при запуске программы из NetBeans - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

Запускаю программу через NetBeans:

```
package com.mycompany.analyzeresumer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AnalyzeResumer extends Application{
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        launch(args);
    }
     
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")));
        stage.setTitle("Resume analyzer");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.analyzeresumer;

/**
 *
 * @author Sergei
 */
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button b1;

    @FXML
    private Button b2;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        b1.setOnAction(event -> {
        
            System.out.println("Wow");
        });
    }
}
```

И выводиться такая ошибка:

```
 Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at com.mycompany.analyzeresumer.AnalyzeResumer.start(AnalyzeResumer.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:187)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.mycompany.analyzeresumer.AnalyzeResumer
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  4.536 s
Finished at: 2021-05-23T22:02:04+03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project AnalyzeResumer: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если запустить через Idea то все работает, но мне необходим запуск через NetBeans, подскажите может кто знает как решить проблему, заранее большое спасибо. (Прошу без комментариев в духе переходи на IntelliJ IDEA, заранее благодарю за помощь и понимание)

Comment: судя по всему, в этой строке Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"))); не подгружается sample.fxml из ваших ресурсов. если этот файл на месте и путь к нему корреткный, то попробуйте перед именем поставит слеш, т.е. сделать так FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml")));

Comment: Попробовал, все равно выводиться ошибка. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на добавленный рисунок структуры проекта

Comment: почему ваш файл sample.fxml находится в одной директории с джавовскими файлами, а не в папке с ресурсами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")`

`getClass().getResource` - файл ожидается в ресурсной папке.
`("sample.fxml")` - пусть начинается не со слеша, значит он идет относительно `getClass()`
`getClass()` - это `AnalyzeResumer.java` расположен он в `com/mycompany/analyzeresumer/`
повторяем эту структуру в ресурсной папке и кладем туда файл.

**resources/com/mycompany/analyzeresumer/sample.fxml**

Comment: Да все заработало, спасибо большое!